# jQuery wont repeat initial trigger action,

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created 3 divs that when clicked, the main container slides half away 600px and a new container slides in to show more option from the 3 divs.

I managed to get the main to slide half away the new content to show according to the 3 divs options but after closed it doest slide again!

Site Link to be more clear http://www.contractax.com/tax-contractors-edinburgh.html

HTML:

```
<aside>
<h1 class="lato blue">Getting Started</h1>
<ul id="menu_container">
<li id="show_newbus" class="show_hide green">NEW BUSINESS</li>
<li id="show_limited" class="show_hide amber">UMBRELLA vs LIMITED</li>
<li id="show_investigation" class="show_hide red">TAX INVESTIGATIONS</li>
</ul>
</aside>
<!--SLIDES HALF WAY 600px only-->
<div class="main-inner lato blue-underline">
</div>

<div id="#menu_newbus" class="new-business">
<div class="close-bt"></div>
</div>
<div class="why-ltd">
<div class="close-bt show_hide-2"></div>
</div>
<div class="investigation">
<div class="close-bt"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.main-inner {
    width: 1024px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    height: 590px;
}
aside {
float: left;
width: 314px;
padding-top: 10px;
}
aside ul li {
width: 314px;
height: 175px;
float: left;
margin: 5px 0 0 0;
background-color: #e9e9e9;
list-style: none;
font-size: 24px;
line-height: 175px;
text-align: center;
background-image: url(../images/ui/arrow-left.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position-x: 310px;
-webkit-transition: all 350ms ease-out 100ms;
-moz-transition: all 350ms ease-out 100ms;
-ms-transition: all 350ms ease-out 100ms;
-o-transition: all 350ms ease-out 100ms;
transition: all 350ms ease-out 100ms;
}

.new-business {
width: 500px;
height: 525px;
padding: 10px;
display: none;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
position: absolute;
top: 44px;
left: 1050px;
z-index: 1;
border: solid #ccc 1px;
}
.why-ltd {
width: 510px;
height: 525px;
padding: 10px;
display: none;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
position: absolute;
top: 44px;
left: 1050px;
z-index: 1;
overflow-y: scroll;
border: solid #ccc 1px;
}
.investigation {
width: 500px;
height: 525px;
padding: 10px;
display: none;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
position: absolute;
top: 44px;
left: 1050px;
z-index: 1;
overflow-y: scroll;
border: solid #ccc 1px;
}
```

Jquery:

```
//Triger the Slider Open
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".show_hide").click(function () {
        $(".main-inner").animate({right: '600px'}, 500);
                if ($('.new-business,.why-ltd,.investigation').is(":hidden"))
       {   
            $('.main-inner').show('slow');  
       }
       else{ 
                $(".show_hide").toggle("slow");
    return false;
                //end
       }        
    });
        //Button Action
            $( ".close-bt" ).click(function() { 
        $( ".new-business,.why-ltd,.investigation" ).hide( "slow", "linear" );
        });
        $(".close-bt").click(function () {
        $(".main-inner").animate({left: '0px'}, 500);

    });
});


$(".close-bt").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var target = $(this).attr("href");
    $(".main-inner").not(target).animate({left: '0px'}, 500);
    $(target).toggle("slow");
        return false;
});
//Change content
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#show_newbus").click(function(){
         $(".new-business").show();
         $(".why-ltd").hide();
         $(".investigation").hide();
    });

    $("#show_limited").click(function(){
         $("#menu_newbus").hide();
         $(".why-ltd").show();
         $(".investigation").hide();
    });

    $("#show_investigation").click(function(){
         $(".new-business").hide();
         $(".why-ltd").hide();
         $(".investigation").show();
    });
});
```

How can I get it to do what I want?

Comment: remove $(document).ready(function(){ above the $(".show_hide").click(function () function

Comment: tried that didn't work! it seems that I need to use a IF and ELSE to pass a variable but I cant find a solution for that neither, it can go for the first time fine but the action can't repeat!

Comment: remove $(document).ready(function(){ above the all the click events

Comment: I managed to remove some stuff including what yu pointed but I still cant repeat the first action again!, now ive got this: '//Triger the Slider Open
$(".show_hide, .close-bt").click(function () {
        value = $('.main-inner').css('right') === '700px' ? 0 : '700px';
      $('.main-inner').animate({
          right: value
      });
    });
//Button Action
$( ".close-bt" ).click(function() { 
  $( ".new-business,.why-ltd,.investigation" ).hide( "fade" );
});
$(".close-bt").click(function () {
        $(".main-inner").animate({left: '0px'}, 500);
    });'

Comment: Thanks I managed to fix it like that:'jQuery(function () {
    jQuery('.show_hide').click(function () {
        var index = $(this).index(),
            newTarget = jQuery('.main-inner').eq(index).animate({left: '-600px'}, 500);
        jQuery('.main-inner').not(newTarget).animate({left: '-600px'}, 500);

    });
});'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed:

```
jQuery(function () {
jQuery('.show_hide').click(function () {
    var index = $(this).index(),
        newTarget = jQuery('.main-inner').eq(index).animate({left: '-600px'}, 500);
    jQuery('.main-inner').not(newTarget).animate({left: '-600px'}, 500);

});
```

});

We have found the solution reading jQuery Documentation >-)
[Jquery .index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/)

Thanks for the Help.